# Scale settings not appearing in N Sidebar in Blender for Linux

Tags: mesh

I am working with a mesh cube.
I changed it from default splash cube to cereal-box shape.
I scaled it with -- Ctrl-A > Scale --

But I can't find the scale setting in the N sidebar.
There is no "Item" tag in the sidebar
All done in object mode. Edit mode is not available

Any suggestions appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if your visual settings are different, but your object is red, meaning that it is selected but not active... box need to be active(orange) for item settings to appear, try to select it again

Comment: @MikoCG That's definitely the answer

Comment: To me it seems that the outline on the object is orange. I configured my lines to be thicker in Preferences.

Comment: The box was selected by box select. The top menu was set to uvmap and the screen was divided into layout, uvmap and nodes. I selected layout in the top menu, the other 2 editors disappeared and the scale settings reappeared. Then I selected uvmap again the scale setting remained in layout. Is this a bug?