# Not able to scale or rotate in viewport 3.6 and selection is in red

Tags: 3d-view, transforms, 3d-cursor

[image]

I don't know how or why this happened but now in 3.6 I couldn't scale or rotate any model and when I select the model it looks red not orange, Also the cursor is a bit thick I tried reinstalling to but didn't work
it was working fine but for last two days it has been like this and when I didn't select affect only as you see,
If you know why this happen do let me know and Thanks

Comment: Could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I guess the blend file would be good... it looks like there is another object selected as well and that is the active one. Actually a screenshot of the _Outliner_ to see what else is in that scene maybe would have helped as well, but a file even more so.

Comment: no only the cube is the object selected and I opened the file in 3.4 also it is working normally I think in 3.6 something happened with my blender.
similar to this one but his solution didn't work for me
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237081/scale-settings-not-appearing-in-n-sidebar-in-blender-for-linux

Comment: So maybe share your file so that we try it with 3.6?

Comment: it is default within blender not any file every file working the same way but here a example working good in 3.4 and 4.0 alpha also but something odd happening with my 3.6 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GSeDwPyb6UlhnStePQx3xDIIFkfLS2oQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes it works fine here with 3.6.2

Comment: I stated the bug in blender developers site, hope they give a solution